# Angular custom style unit with directive or pipe

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I've been frustrated recently by the lack of possibility to specify CSS font size (for example but not only) relatively to parent (not viewport...). So I've tried to make my life easier using Angular features.

My idea was simple: **create a directive (or a pipe?) that allow the use of a custom unit like vw/vh but relative to parent** (I've called them pw/ph).
After lot's of trial and error (I'm no Angular guru) I still don't have something satisfying.

## First I came up with this directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[parentAdaptedStyle]'
})
export class AdaptDirective {
  @Input() public parentAdaptedStyle: string;

  private static regexp: RegExp = /(\d+|\d*.\d)pw|(\d+|\d*.\d)ph/g;
  private dims = { "pw": 0, "ph": 0 };

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  @HostBinding('style') get style() {
    if (!this.parentAdaptedStyle) {
      return "";
    }

    // Update parent values
    this.dims["pw"] = this.el.nativeElement.parentElement.clientWidth * .01;
    this.dims["ph"] = this.el.nativeElement.parentElement.clientHeight * .01;

    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(this.parentAdaptedStyle.replace(AdaptDirective.regexp, this.replacer));
  }

  private replacer = (match, wv, hv, offset, string) => {
    return wv ? parseFloat(wv) * this.dims["pw"] + "px" : parseFloat(hv) * this.dims["ph"] + "px";
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
  <div parentAdaptedStyle="font-size: 4pw">My title with parent relative font size</div>
```

This is working but I found **two major drawbacks**:
1. **It's not working on IE 11/Edge**. Styles are not applied. bypassSecurityTrustStyle returns *SafeValue must use [property]=binding: font-size:10.88px (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)*
2. There may be conflicts with other systems using *style* even if different properties are targeted

I tried to work around #1 with no luck...

## Then I tried the pipe way:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'pads',
  pure: false,
})
export class ParentAdaptedStylePipe implements PipeTransform {
  private static regexp: RegExp = /(\d+|\d*.\d)pw|(\d+|\d*.\d)ph/g;
  private dims = { "pw": 0, "ph": 0 };

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  transform(value: string, el: HTMLElement): any {
    // Update parent values
    this.dims["pw"] = el.parentElement.clientWidth * .01;
    this.dims["ph"] = el.parentElement.clientHeight * .01;

    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value.replace(ParentAdaptedStylePipe.regexp, this.replacer));
  }

  private replacer = (match, wv, hv, offset, string) => {
    return wv ? parseFloat(wv) * this.dims["pw"] + "px" : parseFloat(hv) * this.dims["ph"] + "px";
  }

}
```

**Usage:**

```
<div #title1 [style.fontSize]="'4pw' | pads:title1">My title with parent relative font size</div>
```

The major drawback is that you need to pass the element as an argument to the pipe (as it cannot be injected). This is quite easy on a single element using *#id* but I couldn't find an easy way to do it on *ngFor elements (I got it working hacking around quite a bit).

**Long story short: how would you guys properly implement (in Angular) a custom style unit system that's easy to use and don't get in the way of other styles ?**